# How to force Chromium to render an opened file without HTML extension?

Tags: chromium

I have an HTML file on my local machine:

`echo '<h1>Hello Chromium</h1>' > test`

If I open it using `chromium test`, it does not render the page, but shows the source code. The same file being named `test.html` and opened with `chromium test.html`, opens in chromium and is rendered.

How can I force Chromium to render local files without an HTML extension in their filename?

NB: the context is that I'd like to open HTML documents from mutt, which are stored in `/tmp` without the `.html` extension.

Comment: HTML cannot be identified by looking at magic numbers or anything the like. How would Chrome be able to reliably guess the file type?

Comment: @DanielB I'm not saying that Chrome is doing something wrong. But how can I force it to do what I want? Maybe there is an option `-mimetype text/html` or something similar I couldn't find while googling.

Comment: @DanielB A lot of HTML files have a variant of <!DOCTYPE html> as the first line. Firefox accepts this, but Chrome/Chromium does not, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, the simplest solution would be to start the
Command Prompt (cmd), navigate to the folder, and enter the command :

```
ren * *.html
```

This would have the advantage of not changing the setup of Chrome.
You would need to download the files into an empty folder.

Comment: ...that doesn't sound very good for any other files in the directory.

Comment: @Stackstuck: When downloading one can choose an empty folder.

Comment: ...that's not stated in the question.